# Issues With CSS Background Transition In Responsive Header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a header that becomes smaller on scroll made for [my site](http://tremor.yt/Site/Creators.html). It is working pretty well, but despite the transitions being included in the CSS, the images in the header are only transitioning smoothly when the small header transforms into the large on (on scroll up) and not vice-versa. It looks sort of jumpy/glitchy now.

Here's my CSS for the images:

Logo:

```
.Logo.small:hover {
    background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 73;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
          -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.6s;
    transition: height 0.6s;
          -webkit-transition: width 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.6s;
    transition: width 0.6s;
}
.Logo:hover {
  background: url("images/LogoHover.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  width: 81px;
  height: 85px;
  z-index: 70;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
}
.Logo {
    background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    width: 81px;
    height: 85px;
    z-index: 73;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
    -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
.Logo.small {
    background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 73;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
    -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
```

Social Icon 1:

```
.Icon_BG1 {
  background: url("images/IconBG.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 905px;
  top: 26px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 80;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
.Icon_BG1.small {
  background: url("images/IconBG.png") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 905px;
  top: 10px;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 80;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
.Icon_BG1.small:hover {
  background: url("images/IconBGHover.png") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 905px;
  top: 10px;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 80;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;

}
.Icon_BG1:hover {
  background: url("images/IconBGHover.png") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:905px;
  top: 26px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 80;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
}
```

Social Icon 2:

```
.Icon_BG_2 {
  background: url("images/IconBG2.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 960px;
  top: 26px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 82;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
.Icon_BG_2.small {
  background: url("images/IconBG2.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 960px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 82;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
.Icon_BG_2.small:hover {
  background: url("images/IconBGHover2.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 960px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 82;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
}
.Icon_BG_2:hover {
  background: url("images/IconBGHover2.png") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:960x;
  top: 26px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 82;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its because you are using `background-size` to resize the images and not `transform`

use

```
transform: scale(xx);
```

for resizing